# What is the dominant style for parenthesization of Ruby function calls?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, parentheses

Say I have `func_a` and `func_b` which both take one argument, and I want to pass the result of `func_b` to `func_a`.

What is the most common way to parenthesize this?

1. `func_a func_b input`
2. `func_a func_b(input)`
3. `func_a(func_b input)`
4. `func_a(func_b(input))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to scan source to find the "most common".

I try to write what makes sense under the circumstances, but would almost always use either:

```
func_a func_b(arg)
func_a(func_b(arg))
```

If the functions are named things that "sound like" a sentence or phrase, then I'll drop as many parens as I can.

```
func_a func_b arg
```

In other words, if it sounds like something I'd say out loud, I'll write it like I'd say it--a sentence or phrase.

If it doesn't sound like something I'd say in real life, needs parens to enhance clarity, etc. then I'll write it like I'm writing code, because it sounds/looks like code.

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you the *the most common way*, but my personal opinion.

I would reject version one `func_a func_b input`. It's too confusing, you don't see if input is the parameter of func_b, or if it is the 2nd parameter of func_a.

I prefer version four, it shows explicit, what's the parameter for what (and you see, what is a methodname and what's a variable).
But I would add spaces before and after the parenthesis:

```
func_a( func_b( input ))
```

or

```
func_a( func_b(input) )
```

Comment: Ew; I've never understood spaces after opening/before closing parens.

Comment: I agree that `func_a func_b input` is confusing, but technically it's not actually ambiguous. Since Ruby doesn't have currying, `input` is definitely not a second parameter of `func_a` (which would be `func_a func_b, input`). However, the fact that the entire understanding of the line hinges on the presence/absence of a tiny character (a comma), it does seem like bad practice.

Comment: @Dave Don't try to learn ABAP, there the spaces are necessary. In my case: After some years with ABAP, I'm used to do it and when I read code, my brain can easier parse the code with spaces. I think, it's a confirmed habit for me.